# Best practice for querying API Gateway (Lambda) from Front End for unauthenticated users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Looking to move a legacy application to serverless using Lambda for back-end logic but am unsure what the best practices are for making API Gateway requests from front-end while preventing users from querying the Gateway directly. Users are all unauthenticated but we would still like some sort of rate limiting per user.

**Approach 1**

Host static content (html, js, etc.) on S3. JS on pages queries gateway to fetch back-end data and get presigned URLs for images and videos on S3.

With this approach I am concerned users will be able to query the Gateway directly instead of going through the UI. This programmatic access could be difficult to prevent and result in unexpected expenses.

**Approach 2**

No static content from S3, instead every page will be served via Lambda. Lighter static content could be sent directly from Lambda and larger images and videos would come from presigned S3 URLs.

This would prevent users from examining front-end -> back-end requests since they would only receive the fully assembled html. Concerned this approach would increase lambda run time and expense.

Comment: how do users authenticate on the front end presently?  API GW can have authorizers so you can have the back end issues tokens to the front end that are used to make requests, this would make things more difficult for direct back end access...

Comment: @JDD There is no authentication for the front end it is publicly accessible. Similar user experience to a website like imgur where there is access to unauthenticated users including service static content and images but also authenticated user only views. This logic is all PHP right now.